# Why no error is raised when I declare a matrix that has 0 as a dimension in C?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, struct

So I spent like 1 hour checking what's wrong with my code before seeing that I wrote a 0 instead of 10.

Why was I not getting some kind of error or at least a segment fault when I was trying to write and read from this matrix?

Also, is this a correct way of putting a matrix in a structure?

Thanks for your time.

```
typedef struct G
{
    int initilized;
    char matrix[9][9][0];

} grid;
```

Comment: Arrays of size zero are legal in certain compilers as extension

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's surprising that they would allow arrays of zero length objects though. Sure `char matrix[0][9][10];` would be understandable. GCC supported that to implement flexible array members before they were standardized as `char matrix[][9][10]`.

Comment: As for "why no error when reading or writing": writing outside the bounds of an array is always *undefined behavior* and never guarantees an error, segfault, or anything else predictable.  Probably what happened is you ended up reading/writing whatever data happened to come after that object in memory; it is not easy for the system to detect that without adding a lot of overhead to your program at runtime.

Comment: @IanAbbott: It could make sense if the dimensions were constants defined or computed somewhere else.  If one of them ends up being zero, it could be convenient that the whole multidimensional array is effectively just omitted.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, if they were VLAs, but struct/union members cannot be VLAs.

Comment: @IanAbbott: I'm thinking of the dimensions being defined (via macros) as complicated constant expressions, or perhaps with values coming from some computation done before compilation by some other script.  The arrays would not need to be VLAs in that case.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Like `char matrix[9][9][N_WHATSITS];`.  If you're building for a platform that doesn't have any whatsits, then `#define N_WHATSITS 0` will avoid having any overhead.  Easier than having to wrap every such line in `#if N_WHATSITS > 0`.  (Presumably you process the array with something like `for (i=0; i < N_WHATSITS; i++) { ... }` that becomes an empty loop and will be optimized out.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Also, apparently GCC supports VLAs in struct/union members as an extension, but of course only for struct/union types defined in a block scope.

Comment: @NateEldredge I concede it makes some sort of sense.

Answer (score 4):

`-Wpedantic` will raise a warning.

```
warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array 'matrix' [-Wpedantic]
    4 |     char matrix[9][9][0];
      |          ^~~~~~
```